# Making Objects that Don't Inherit from IEnumerable<> Queryable via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, class, object, collections

I have a class called `IDCollection` which is *not* actually a `List<>`, `Dictionary<,>`, or similar `IEnumerable`-based type. Though it does **have an indexer**, it's based on a private `Dictionary<string, ID>` called `innerList`, so **objects of the class themselves are not lists**, nor does it hold key value pairs or a collection of items through its own `this` accessor.

**Is it possible to make an `IDCollection` object queryable in a LINQ expression? If so, how?**

For example, suppose the object is called `testIdColl`. In that case...

```
from KeyValuePair<string, ID> k in testIDColl
select k;
```

etc.

And is the `IQueryable` interface involved at all?

Comment: So a solution that also implemented IEnumerable<> is not good for you? Why?

Comment: @SimpleVar I didn't want to give `IDCollections` all the methods that are built in to `IEnumerable<>`. I wanted very close control and what it can do and how simple it is. I guess this little complication, so to speak, didn't invade my train of thought a little earlier. :)

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` so I suppose your best solution is to throw `NotSupportedException` in any method you wish to not support, and fully implement the `IQueryable<T>` interface.

Comment: Either implement `IEnumerable<>` or expose inner list as public enumerable property. First solution makes queries to look more natural, second doesn't give all enumerable methods to your interface.

Comment: @Jenguinie - There's effectively only one method to implement on `IEnumerable<T>`. What's wrong with implementing that?

Comment: @Dennis Wouldn't exposing `innerList` make all of its methods exposed as well? And then things would go haywire.

Comment: @SimpleVar I suppose that could work, but that would make things a little messy, since the methods would all still be exposed either way.

Comment: @Jenguinie - What "methods" would be exposed???

Comment: @Jenguinie: if you'll expose it as `IEnumerable<>` then no, it will not.

Comment: @Dennis Ahhhh, thanks. I can try that, though the neater solution would be if an object of `IDCollection` could be used itself. I'm not well versed in using interfaces yet, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: @Dennis Actually, all of its methods are exposed. I just created a property with the signature `public IDictionary<string, ID> List`, and an accessor which returns `innerList`, and when I use it with some object `testIDColl`, I can access all of the methods of the `innerList` dictionary that are simply built into the `Dictionary` class.

Comment: Is there no syntax, like an `operator` method, that could be used to create this effect?

Comment: @Jenguinie - No, they are not exposed. See my answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, I'm a little confused. I'm working in Visual Studio, and when I enter something like, given the exposed property `List`, `testIDColl.List.`, many suggestions for methods come up, and I don't want any of those to be available. Those are the methods I'm talking about.

Comment: @Jenguinie - Do you mean `Aggregate`, `All`, `Any`, etc?

Comment: @Enigmativity Exactly, such that `testIDColl.Aggregate<T>()` is still exposed without a `List` property of some sort. Even after trying your solution, they're all there, though I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jenguinie - That's just the list of extension methods exposed by `System.Linq`. If you want to use your object in a LINQ query you **need** them to be there. You can't hide them without losing ability to use LINQ.

Comment: @Enigmativity I see. But technically, couldn't `innerList` be edited by using those methods? I'm confused about what is and what isn't exposed with your solution.

Comment: @Jenguinie - No, `innerList` **can not** be edited because it is only exposed via `GetEnumerator()`. Not one of those methods will add or remove members of `innerList`.

Comment: @Enigmativity That makes sense. So it can't be mutated, only accessed. Thanks again for your help. I accepted Jakub Lortz's solution because of the clarity he brought in explaining how the extension methods work, but I wish I could accept both answers, as I'm using yours, practically speaking.

Comment: @Jenguinie: do not expose it as `IDictionary<,>`. Expose is as `IEnumerable<,>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to implement `IEnumerable<T>`. It's only one method, which you can usually delegate to inner collection's `GetEnumerator()` or implement easily with `yield return`.

The name of your type (`IDCollection`) suggests that it should implement `IEnumerable<T>`, probably some other collection interface (e.g. `ICollection<T>`, `IReadonlyCollection<T>`).

If for some reason you don't want to use `IEnumerable<T>`, you can still make it work. First you need to understand how the compiler processes query expressions.

A LINQ query expression is first translated by the compiler to a series of method calls. For example the query expression

```
from KeyValuePair<string, int> item in collection
where item.Key == "abc"
select item.Value;
```

Is translated to

```
testIDColl
    .Cast<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
    .Where(item => item.Key == "abc")
    .Select(item => item.Value);
```

All you need to do to use a type as a source in a query expression is to make the above code compile. It means you will need `Cast`, `Where`, `Select` (and others too, like `GroupBy`, `OrderBy`) methods either as instance methods or extension methods.

For example the following class and extension methods will make the above query expression compile (although the methods don't do anything at all):

```
class IDCollection
{

}

static class IDCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IDCollection Cast<TResult>(this IDCollection source)
    {
        return source;
    }

    public static IDCollection Where(this IDCollection source, Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, bool> selector)
    {
        return source;
    }

    public static IDCollection Select<TResult>(this IDCollection source, Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, TResult> selector)
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Instance methods will work too:

```
class IDCollection
{
    public IDCollection Cast<TResult>()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IDCollection Where(Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, bool> selector)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IDCollection Select<TResult>(Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, TResult> selector)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This really clarifies @Enigmativity's answer. If not using `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ID>`, I don't have to write/override any of the methods used by LINQ, right?

Comment: It would be really useful if you could write the implementation for the instance. Right now it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Jenguinie All the methods for `IEnumerable<T>` and some other types (like `IQueryable`, `ParallelQuery`) are already implemented, you don't need to do anything extra to use them if your class implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity What error do you get? It compiles for me.

Comment: @JakubLortz - Sorry, it compiles, but it just doesn't return anything. If I have an inner list with two elements and I perform a query I only ever get back a single instance of `IDCollection` and never a collection of `KeyValuePair<string, int>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, the only purpose of the code is to compile the first query expression. It doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @JakubLortz - How does that help the OP?

Comment: @Enigmativity It helps the OP understand how query expressions are processed. There are 2 reasons why this solution might be useful - one is when you have a type that semantically is not `IEnumerable` (i can't think of any example right now, maybe there are some), the other when the type is an `IEnumerable`, but you want a different behavior of queries (like `IQueryable` and `ParallelQuery`). The OP's case is neither, but it's still worth to know how query expression work.

Comment: @JakubLortz - I can't think of situations where either of those things apply, but you're right that neither is what the OP wants. So you've provided an answer that doesn't practically help the OP. It's only a theoretical discussion? This is now very confusing for him. Why create something that is syntactically correct, but semantically incorrect?

Comment: @Enigmativity No, it's not necessarily confusing. I think it's helpful to have this information for some point later. I'd like to learn as much as I can and extract as much as I can from any question I ask on Stack Overflow, so I feel this answer is the most helpful, though yours is the more practical of the two.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you would need to do to your class:

```
public class IDCollection : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ID>>
{
    private IDictionary<string, ID> List = new Dictionary<string, ID>();

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, ID>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return List.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you could run this code:

```
var testIDColl = new IDCollection();

var query =
    from KeyValuePair<string, ID> k in testIDColl
    select k;
```

If you want you could make the entire `IEnumerable<...>` interface private like so:

```
public class IDCollection : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ID>>
{
    private IDictionary<string, ID> List = new Dictionary<string, ID>();

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, ID>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ID>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return List.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return List.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now nothing is directly exposed.

I created an implementation of the three instance methods from Jakub's answer:

```
public class IDCollection
{
    private IDictionary<string, ID> List = new Dictionary<string, ID>() { { "x", new ID() }, } ;

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ID>> Where(Func<KeyValuePair<string, ID>, bool> selector)
    {
        return List.Where(selector);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TResult>(Func<KeyValuePair<string, ID>, TResult> selector)
    {
        return List.Select(selector);
    }
}
```

The `Cast` method was not needed to perform basic queries.

I would suggest adding an explicit `AsEnumerable()` method instead to expose the full range of LINQ operators.

This would be the simplest and most robust way of doing queries:

```
public class IDCollection
{
    private IDictionary<string, ID> List = new Dictionary<string, ID>() { { "x", new ID() }, } ;

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ID>> AsEnumerable()
    {
        return List.Select(x => x);
    }
}
```

The queries would have to look like:

```
var query =
    from k in testIDColl.AsEnumerable()
    where k.Key == "x"
    select k;
```